# 2D numpy array showing as 1D

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray `train_data` of length `200`, where every row is another ndarray of length `10304`.

However when I print `np.shape(train_data)`, I get `(200, 1)`, and when I print `np.shape(train_data[0])` I get `(1, )`, and when I print `np.shape(train_data[0][0])` I get `(10304, )`.

I am quite confused with this behavior as I supposed the first `np.shape(train_data)` should return `(200, 10304)`.

Can someone explains to me why this is happening, and how could I get the array to be in shape of `(200, 10304)`?

Comment: What is the dtype of the `train_data`?

Comment: @DavidS `train_data.dtype` is `object`, `train_data.dtype[0]` is `object`, `train_data.dtype[0][0]` is `uint8`.

Comment: the subarrays must vary in size, so it can't make  a 2d array from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the arrays are constructed to be arrays of objects. Basically each element in the array is pointing to another array of size (1, ) which points to another array of size (10304, ). This is not equivalent to a normal ndarray in numpy so the shape is not recognized correctly. You can check this by looking at the dtypes.

To replicate what you see:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty(200, dtype='object')
for i in range(200):
    temp_arr = np.empty(1, dtype='object')
    temp_arr[0] = np.zeros(10304)
    arr[i] = temp_arr
print(arr.shape)
print(arr[0].shape)
print(arr[0][0].shape)

(200,)
(1,)
(10304,)
```

To get the (200, 10304) array back you need to "unpack" them:

```
new_arr = np.array([x[0] for x in arr])

#(200, 10304)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that's happening, try reshaping the array:

B = np.reshape(A, (-1, 2))

Comment: This splits it into 2 columns. So from `(200, 1)` to `(100, 2)`. Not exactly what I want.

Comment: Oh, ok I thought that would work, hope you find out soon!